# convert xScale from ordinal to time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a functional chart https://jsfiddle.net/lucksp/crwb4v5u/ that creates the xScale with `ordinal()` since my x-axis of hours is not using a date object, just strings in 15 minute intervals for a 24 hour period: `['0:00', '0:15', '0:30', '0:45', '1:00', ..... '14:00'... '23:45', '24:00']`.
I am at the point of wanting to include a tooltip for the bar & area at once that uses the vertical line which follows the mouse because there are 2 sets of data using 2 different chart types.  Similar to https://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/dL1qp1t6/ or http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/44ffca2877d0132572cb or http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136

In order to do this, one must `invert` the convert pixel coordinates into ordinal data range. HOWEVER, the ordinal scale does not allow for invert.  So the way to do this is to use the `time.scale()`.

I have tried to model the use of this scale from these examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/hpjqt1dL/4 
  this gives a nice date object to work with but the d3 parse format errors on the string it receives.

date object example:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
todayMillis = today.getTime();

data.forEach(function(d) {
    var parts = d.time.split(/:/);
    var timePeriodMillis = (parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 * 60 * 1000) +
                           (parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 * 1000) + 
                           (parseInt(parts[2], 10) * 1000);

    d.time = new Date();
    d.time.setTime(todayMillis + timePeriodMillis);
});
```

- http://bl.ocks.org/anupsavvy/9513382 (click on the blue button to select a date which displays hour intervals)

I like this because it's also using a string "time" but I don't love the way the domain is set:

```
xScale.domain([new Date(0, 0, 0,dataset[0][0].time,0, 0, 0),new Date(0, 0, 0,dataset[0][dataset[0].length-1].time,0, 0, 0)])
```

- Date parsing: http://jsfiddle.net/aWJtJ/8/

however, I either get an error on the area chart or in the  `.attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())` or the axis doesn't render.

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate.parse(d.datestr);
});
```

So at this point, I am not sure what is causing the issues.  Since this is my first deep dive into d3, I am hoping for additional explanations on how to convert from ordinal to time.

Comment: What is the value of `dataset[0][0].time`? If it's something like "0:00" then `new Date(0, 0, 0, dataset[0][0].time, 0, 0, 0)` will return an invalid date. When called like that, the Date constructor expects only numeric arguments, not strings like "0:00".

Comment: what's a numeric version example?  if I create a new date() object returns Tue May 02 2017 21:18:26 GMT-0600 format...

Comment: Something like `new Date(2017,4,3,23,10,5)` for 3 May, 2017 11:10:05 pm. The example at *bl.ocks.org* is using a single digit for the hours so `new Date(0, 0, 0,dataset[0][0].time,0, 0, 0)` is effectively `new Date(0, 0, 0, "2" ,0, 0, 0)` if *dataset[0][0].time* is "2". That will make a date for 31 December, 1899 (since a 0 year is treated as 1900, 0 month as January and 0 date as the last day of the previous month).

Comment: in the bl.ocks.org example, `dataset[0][0].time` is equal to `{
            "time": "0",
            "y": 0
        },` while the other end `dataset[0][dataset[0].length-1].time` is `{
            "time": "23",
            "y": 1
        }`

Comment: if I only need a 24 hour scale, do I really need a date object?  Is there another way to bisect the string value I pass in?  This example https://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/dL1qp1t6/ doesn't use a date object, but the scales are linear which isn't truly correct unless I use 1,2,3,4 as my X scale and then manually enter the ticks?

Comment: @RobG i added links above for example tooltips with vertical line...

Comment: For your information, [there is a reason](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3022) why *ordinal.invert* doesn't exist. However, it's not complicated to create your own `invert` function. Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40574104/5768908 And also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20766269/5768908

Comment: thanks @GerardoFurtado .  I updated my fiddle with your example.  https://jsfiddle.net/lucksp/crwb4v5u/

Comment: One more question now that I am able to compare the Bars with the Tooltip data:  Why do the x-scale bars not start at 0,0 (bottom left corner) but the tooltip does?

Comment: I'm not understanding this question. Btw, `0,0` is the **top** left corner.

Comment: yes, 0,0 is top left for SVG, but for the chart, 0,0 is the corner of X & Y axis.  If you view my fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/lucksp/crwb4v5u/ you can see the scrolling tooltip shows 0:00 on x in a different location than the first bar.  Here is a screenshot:  https://screencast.com/t/uIu5mYEaM  I do not understand what is incorrect in my d3 code

Comment: @PhilipL That's another problem, which is easy to fix. However, I advise you to ask it in a new post.